# python pymysql set autocommit false fails

Tags: python, mysql, autocommit

my script reads MYSQL UPDATE queries from a file and then should execute them at once by using autocommit = 0. However, if I remove `conn.commit()` it still runs one by one, although I have not commited. Where is the error?

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='x', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock',user='x', passwd='x', db='x')
fileHandle = open ( 'mysqlout.txt' )
fileList = fileHandle.readlines()
fileHandle.close()
i = 1
weiter = input("Execute MYSQL file? ")
if (weiter == 'y'):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SET autocommit = 0')
    conn.commit()
    for fileLine in fileList: #-----each line is an UPDATE...query
        cur.execute(fileLine)
        i = i + 1
        print(i," ---",round(i / len(fileList),3))
#conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: is my code above correct at all???

Answer (score 7):

Transactions are not supported with MyISAM storage engine in MySQL. Only InnoDB suports ACID transactions.

Quoting [Transactions and Atomic Operations MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html):

> In transactional terms, MyISAM tables effectively always operate in
>   autocommit = 1 mode.

You should [check storage engine for your tables](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/find-storage-engine-of-mysql-table-2009-09-17/):

```
mysql> SELECT table_name,engine FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
       WHERE table_schema=DATABASE();
+--------------+--------+
| table_name   | engine |
+--------------+--------+
| stats        | MyISAM |
+--------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Move tables to a [MySQL storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-engines.html) that supports transactions.

Comment: thanks. I have a MyISAM engine. Can I convert it or do I have to create a new database/table with different engine and import the data?

Comment: [ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Did that but still does not work. Still runs each query one by one

Comment: how do you test it? You can modify your python script and put a `a=raw_imput("import in pause to check transaction")` before last commit? While script is paused you can test transaction.

Comment: how can I test transaction while the script is paused?

Comment: open terminal, execute `mysql -u username -p databasename` and make a query over updated table. If you see previous values is dued to transaction in still not commited, if you see new values something are wrong.

Comment: I saw that it seems to work, but very strangely. 1st it runs alle the UPDATE queries, which is quite faste and then commits. Commiting takes like 5s. However, the Python program is finished, but I dont see any data. I takes like an additional minute of lag when appearantly the server does something in the background. I will look into LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Take a look to repeatable read concept. Perhap is the reason of your "1 minute" delay.

Comment: I am not really a programmer, but trying to create a script for helping me get my work done faster. I think I understand these 4 different isolation concepts, but not quite sure how they relate to my delay problem. When I commit 6000 queries, I would guess they are done in parallel. However, each query is unique, there are no repeated reads, so every query accesses one unique data point in the table. I tried changing the isolation level for the session but it doesnt have an effect. Again commiting is done fast, but the data only appear with a 2 minute delay....

Comment: @user670186, only for test purposes, when you are waiting for "data refresh" before python commit, try to write commit in SQL and re-read data. A commit will finish current transaction. 2 minutes is too much for 6000 updates. I hope this achieve your issue. regards.

Comment: @user670186, Has the post answer your question about commits? Is the answer a solution to your question?